# Android date picker fragment change to spinner

Tags: java, android, datepicker

I'm trying to change the date picker style to spinner for one date picker, others shall remain default.

I've tried:

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        private int style;

        DatePickerFragment(int xml) {
            style = xml;
        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();             
            final DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            LayoutInflater inflater = requireActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            datePickerDialog.setView(inflater.inflate(style, null));
            return datePickerDialog;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            Log.i("DatePicker", "received date from picker: " + day + "." + month + "." + year);
        }
    }
```

with style XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DatePicker xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/datePicker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:datePickerMode="spinner"
            android:calendarViewShown="false" />
```

but whenever I enter a date in the spinner and hit OK, the current (todays) date is logged in the `onDateSet` method and not the chosen one in the date picker.

I also tried to overwrite the OK button with:

```
datePickerDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "asd", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Log.i("DatePicker", "received date from picker2: " + datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().getDayOfMonth() + "." + datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().getMonth()+1 + "." + datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().getYear());
                }
            });
```

but without change.

From my understanding and the behavior, I'm creating some overlay with `inflater.inflate(style, null)` where I select the date, but the overlay values are not populated.

How can I use the inflater to change the date picker style?

Note...I can't:

- change the style since I also need "regular" date pickers.
- Use a new Activity, I want to stick with fragments.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Root cause:** DatePickerDialog class has a final field named `mDatePicker`, this field is initialized once inside the constructor, so when you call.

```
final DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

From that point, the `mDatePicker` field cannot be re-assigned to any value because its modify is `final`. When you call `setView` on the dialog, it just changes the view of the dialog without knowing the `datePicker` inside your custom layout.

That explains why when you change the date on the custom layout and hit OK button, it collects the value of `mDatePicker` to return your fragment instead of `datePicker` in your custom layout.

**Solution 1:** Using a custom style to change the date picker mode to spinner, **but requires min API 21**

Step 1: Define a style in styles.xml file

```
<style name="customDatePickerStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/customDatePicker</item>
</style>

<style name="customDatePicker" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
    <item name="android:calendarViewShown">false</item>
</style>
```

Step 2: In DatePickerFragment class

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        return new DatePickerDialog(requireActivity(),
                R.style.customDatePickerStyle,
                this,
                calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        Log.i("DatePicker", "received date from picker: " + day + "." + month + "." + year);
    }
}
```

**Solution 2:** Create own custom date picker fragment by using a custom layout file, work for all APIs

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

    private int style;
    private DatePicker mDatePicker;

    DatePickerFragment(int xml) {
        style = xml;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = requireActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(style, null);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        mDatePicker = view.findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
        mDatePicker.init(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                null);

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity())
                .setView(view)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, this)
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, this)
                .create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        switch (which) {
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                mDatePicker.clearFocus();
                onDateSet(mDatePicker,
                        mDatePicker.getYear(),
                        mDatePicker.getMonth(),
                        mDatePicker.getDayOfMonth());
                break;
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                dialog.dismiss();
                break;
        }
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        Log.i("DatePicker", "received date from picker: " + day + "." + month + "." + year);
    }
}
```